# IAM user cannot switch views between account in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

When I login as IAM user, I did not find "View data" option in Cloudwatch, even I set Admin access to this user. Login as root user is fine.
[image]

Is there something wrong or what might causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Cross-account sharing has been enabled under Settings page of Cloudwatch.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Under Enable account selector setting, check "Show selector in the console" option, it must be configured for each IAM users who want switch views between accounts. I thought this configuration is global.
[image]